# How to Call ArcHydro Tools in Stand Alone Python Script

Tags: python, raster, arc-hydro

I am currently using ArcGIS ArcHydro tools to perform 'Catchment Polygon Processing'.

However, it is proving time consuming to perform this for multiple rasters.
How might a write a python script to import ArcHydro tools?

Comment: Are you just looking for: arcpy.CatchmentPolyProcessing_archydro()? What versions are you using? Do you have the script started? See if the python automation slides [here](https://prezi.com/ueopyqx7kb2d/automating-arc-hydro-with-python/) answer any of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered there is an ArcHydro Tools Python toolbox which is installed in the ArcHydro Set-up. C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes

This covers most ArcHydro tools contained in the main interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can import Archydro like any other module

```
import ArcHydroTools
```

Then you can access functions like

```
ArcHydroTools.CatchmentPolyProcessing(...)
```

Comment: Note that for standalone scripts one has to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\WaterUtils\ArcHydro\bin` to *PYTHONPATH* besides everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Like Richard G suggested, the toolbox is the way to go. I had nothing but trouble trying to import functions via:

```
import ArcHydroTools
```

An example:

```
import arcpy
toolbox = ('C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.3/ArcToolbox'
           '/Toolboxes/Arc Hydro Tools Python')
arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolbox)
arcpy.LevelDEM_archydropy(Input_Raw_DEM_Raster="demfixed",
                          Input_Lake_Feature_Class="watbody.shp",
                          Output_Level_DEM_Raster="D:/leveldem")
```

Comment: "nothing but trouble" is not a good description of a problem. You don't need to import toolbox nor ArcHydroTools. If you'd like to use *arcpy* style calls, you'd want `arcpy.gp.DEMReconditioning_archydro` (tested with ArcGIS 10.5). P.S. I believe Richard suggested *archydropy* instead of *archydro*.